# Why does GeoServer WCS 1.1.1 Returns NullPointerException for GetCoverage?

Tags: geoserver, wcs

I'm making a request for my WCS service in the 1.1.1 version of the protocol.
I should note that the same area is working correctly with 1.0.0 and also with 2.0.1.

The geoserver version I’m using is 2.21.0

The request is below:

```
http://GEOSERVER_IP:8080/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCoverage&Identifier=cite:4326oparea&format=geotiff&crs=EPSG:4326&width=256&height=256&BoundingBox=-117.421875,32.54681317351515,-117.0703125,32.84267363195431
```

That makes the server respond with a Null error:

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1 http://54.247.181.28:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.1.0/owsAll.xsd">
<ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
<ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.NullPointerException</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Am I doing something wrong in the request, or is that a bug on Geoserver's side? I scoured [their documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wcs/reference.html) and couldn't find much to go on.

Comment: Looking at the WCS 1.1.1 specification (specifications at https://www.ogc.org/standards/wcs)  it would appear your syntax is incorrect.  You probably need `BoundingBox=-32.54681317351515,117.421875,32.84267363195431-117.0703125,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&`

Comment: After adding your suggestions to the url, I get a different exception: ```org.geotools.coverage.processing.EmptyIntersectionException: Crop envelope does not intersect in model space Crop envelope does not intersect in model space``` But the boundingbox is valid. Not sure what's happening there.

Comment: Please add the new information to your question. And for the intersection issue do you have the correct axis order? You can use the wcs request generator under demos to get a working request to compare.

Comment: Should the GetCoverage button in the request generator return an image? All that I get is a text box with a title, for example "North America sample imageryA very rough imagery of North Americanurc:Img_Sample"

Answer (score 1):

A request that works with the GeoServer demo layer nurc:Img_Sample

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wcs?service=WCS&version=1.1.1&request=GetCoverage&Identifier=nurc:Img_Sample&format=image/tiff&crs=EPSG:4326&BoundingBox=20.7052,-130.85168,54.1141,-62.0054,urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326

Notice the axis order in BoundingBox that must be latitude-longitude for urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326.

An .eml file with a .xml part and .tif part is returned.